# Outlook 2010 Creating Odd Space w/ HTML Email

Tags: html, html-email, outlook-2010, inline-styles

Within my html file, I have two columns, within each column is a table. Within each table multiple rows with inline styles. When content in the left column is enough so that it pushes down to a certain point, a white break or space appears in the right column at that spot. If no content reaches that point in the left column, the right column appears just fine, no odd break/white space.

Main send method is mailchimp campaign, but this same thing happens when using the "insert as text" feature in outlook to send html email in the body of a message. The phenomenon is ONLY happening in outlook 2010.

Including an image of the white space in question. The white portion circled should not be there, should be a uniform gray background as seen above and below it. As you see, it breaks the content in half as well. Yet there is no corresponding white space in the left column. Including full code as well, the lines where this is happening is approximately 54 (left column content) and 112 (the link that is breaking in half on the right). I have a feeling outlook is doing this for some other reason and not based on those specific lines in the code, but I don't know that.

[odd white space in right column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiNOC.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color:#EBEBEB"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><br>
<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/916957d8-b90a-4366-aba5-e59a58a974a9.png" width="800" height="195" style="display: block" alt=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="550" style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; font-size:13px; color: #494949; padding: 16px 20px 8px 21px"><strong>JANUARY 2021</strong></td>
            <td width="250" align="right" style="padding: 16px 20px 8px 21px"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/0e3c86e8-d4df-4e03-b6a9-e76d9ac54aac.gif" style="border: none" width="18" height="18" alt=""/> &nbsp;<img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/008a2bf3-c0cd-431b-8375-2b5e150f39b0.gif" style="border: none" width="18" height="18" alt=""/> &nbsp;<img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/9851496c-80b9-4946-af9b-7cfbff69fd6c.gif" style="border: none" width="18" height="18" alt=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="550" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px"><table width="510" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:22px; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px 20px 6px 20px; background-color: #e31837"><strong>A YEAR LIKE NO OTHER</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height: 20px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
                    <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:22px; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px 20px 6px 20px; background-color: #e31837"><strong>A YEAR LIKE NO OTHER</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height: 20px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; border: none"><hr color="#E0E0E0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height: 20px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; border: none"><hr color="#E0E0E0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height: 20px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height: 20px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
                    <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height: 20px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
                    <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
            <td width="250" rowspan="2" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 20px 20px 0px"><table width="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 9px 0px 9px 20px; background-color: #5a5a5a"><strong><span style="font-size: 17px">&#187;</span> AT IN THE NEWS</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #494949; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; background-color: #f1f1f1"><a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adisping Elsumond Minim Exept Est Id Ang</a>  - Philadelphia Business Journal<br>
              <br>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adisping Elsumond Minim Exept Est </a> – St. Louis Business Journal</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/1ab4eb65-27aa-4856-b49e-63ba1e1c31c1.png" style="display: block" width="230" height="130" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #494949; padding: 20px; background-color: #f1f1f1"><a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adisping Elsumond Minim Exept Est Id Ang</a>  - Philadelphia Business Journal<br>
              <br>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur </a> – Missouri Lawyers Weekly</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/1ab4eb65-27aa-4856-b49e-63ba1e1c31c1.png" style="display: block" width="230" height="130" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #494949; padding: 20px; background-color: #f1f1f1"><a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adisping Elsumond Minim Exept Est Id Ang</a>  - Philadelphia Business Journal<br>
              <br>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur </a> – Missouri Lawyers Weekly<br>
              <br>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Akdo</a> –  St. Louis Business Journal</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/1ab4eb65-27aa-4856-b49e-63ba1e1c31c1.png" style="display: block" width="230" height="130" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #494949; padding: 20px; background-color: #f1f1f1"><a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adisping Elsumond Minim Exept Est Id Ang</a>  - Philadelphia Business Journal<br>
              <br>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur </a> – Missouri Lawyers Weekly<br>
              <br>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #005daa">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Akdo</a> –  St. Louis Business Journal</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/1ab4eb65-27aa-4856-b49e-63ba1e1c31c1.png" style="display: block" width="230" height="130" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/1ef099905d4d96754c45a57bf/images/1ab4eb65-27aa-4856-b49e-63ba1e1c31c1.png" style="display: block" width="230" height="130" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #494949; padding: 20px; background-color: #f1f1f1">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#525252" style="font-family:calibri; arial; sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height: 13px; color: #bdbdbd; padding: 10px 10px 15px 15px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
<br>
<br></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This could be a 'page break' gap, caused by Outlook's rendering engine: Word! See https://support.vision6.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/202234760-Why-is-there-white-space-gaps-in-my-email- However, I'd be more concerned with this email not being responsive. Is there any reason why you've gone for a non-responsive email (i.e. responds to mobile and tablet widths, to fit and be readable on such devices)?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As far as the suggestion, I've never seen this sort of white gap in any email I've created over the years, many of them long newsletter types like this one, so I'm not too confident that would be the issue - also the fact that it only happens in the right column, yet the left column is unaffected. Regarding responsiveness, just a lack of knowledge/time to implement such features at the moment.

Comment: Actually, Nathan, I think you may be right. After reading the article you linked and testing on my end - the white break happens in the same spot of the email regardless of the content that's in it. That tells me, for the most part, it doesn't matter what I've coded, Outlook 2010 is just doing what it does. It is a mystery to me why the page break gap appears in the right column only, as the left column is just as tall pixel-wise, yet is unaffected. Now to find out if there's a trick to stop outlook from doing it.